# I accidentally removed windows live from gpedit.msc

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have the latest Windows 10 system.

- I accidentally turned my Windows login account into a live account.
- I tried to turn it into a local user which didn't work (error: 0x80004005).
- I tried to create a new account and migrate everything over but all my old drivers wants me to authenticate them on startup with my windows live password.
- I thought it would be an easy thing to fix after reading this article.

  https://www.petri.com/use-group-policy-to-stop-linking-microsoft-accounts-to-local-domain-logins
- What happened was that the authentication window is blank. The password text field is gone. The yes button is gone.
- I tried to go back into the Group Policy Editor, but I don't have permission to use that either.

How can I make it so that I don't have to log in with my Microsoft account every time I want to give something admin privilege?

Comment: "How can I make it so that I don't have to log in with my Microsoft account every time I want to give something admin privilege?" - Disconnect your Administrator account from your Microsoft Account.  See my detailed [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/1110932/how-do-i-disassociate-email-credentials-from-an-account-in-windows-10/1110949#1110949) on how you do that exactly.  I can't read the article since its behind a pay wall.  "I tried to go back into the Group Policy Editor, but I don't have permission to use that either." - Enable the built-in Administrator user in that case.

Comment: I also wrote an [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) on how to enable the built-in Administrator user.

Comment: Edit your question, so I knew which question to flag this a duplicate of, because I honestly am not entirely sure what your "actual" question is.  Do you want to disconnect your user profile from your Microsoft Account or disable the group policy you enabled by using the built-in Administrator account?