# Issues when Windows 10 Account Username Includes Space

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, path, user-profiles

In most versions of Windows I have used, and currently using Windows 10, having a space within the account username poses problems, particularly with paths and when the input doesn't accept a path with ""[...]"" (I put quotes in quotes). I do not remember how it came to be, but, when creating my account, my home folder now includes a space.

I would like to change (?) my Local account's username to remove the space (that also exists in my home folder) but the online guides and things I tried fail. I have tried changing the profile location in the registry, home folder etc., but something always breaks and my profile cannot load. I always end up having to do a System Restore.

How can I fix this without having to create a new account and move everything to it? I would like to avoid having to create a new account, since settings and customizations will have to be done anew. How can I change the username of my local account and what registry keys and other settings do I have to change to point to my new profile folder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought all OSes did this automatically these days - Full name: Fred Bloggs, username: fbloggs [or fredbloggs]. It's been a while since i set up a win machine, so memory is hazy.

Comment: [Disassociate (Disconnect) your local account from your Microsoft Account, when prompted for a username, choose one that doesn’t have a space in it.  Once you log back into the account associate the local account with your Microsoft Account.  This will effortlessly and seamlessly allow you to change the name of the user’s profile directory.](https://superuser.com/questions/1110932/how-do-i-disassociate-microsoft-account-credentials-from-an-account-in-windows-1/1110949#1110949). While my answer to that question in my opinion is a solution to this question I am hesitant to flag has a duplicate

Comment: @Tetsujin I think that's how I did the mistake with the space. I thought that the name with the space was how the name would appear, without knowing that the actual name of the folder would be the same.

Comment: @Ramhound I thought of that, associating with Microsoft and the dissociating, I just wanted to know if there are alternatives so I don't have to send EVEN MORE private info to Microsoft servers :P

Comment: @Minas - Choose to not synchronize anything, you wanted a method that allows you to avoid creating a new user, the method I describe is that method. There are ways to go about it on previous versions of Windows, but I haven’t to this date, found complete fool proof instructions for that method.  Most questions on the subject typically start off using those incomplete methods, resulting in a broken profile, and thus require help to resolve.

Comment: Yet another trick I learned from you @Ramhound . Thanks! :)

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. Yes, indeed there are a lot of incomplete methods and those are the ones I described that broke my profile and reuired restore. I guess I'll try the foolproof method. Maybe you want to post it as an answer so I can choose it as an answer?

Comment: I already submitted answer to a existing question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find an official way to just change the folder's name to remove the space. As mentioned, in the comments, the account can be converted top a Microsoft Account and then back to a Local Account.