# Windows 11 %USERNAME% still truncated

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, windows-11

I understand that some find this problem negligible, but it really bothers me. I have not known this phenomenon before either.

It's about the problem known to some that since Windows 10(?) Microsoft simply truncates the usernames at directory level to 5 characters - God knows why?

If I follow the following trick to correct Windows' truncated usernames, everything works beautifully. https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-name-of-user-profile-folder-in-windows-11.2133/

"juerg" has become "juergen" again. That is my name and that is what I want to be called on my own computer.

But unfortunately `echo %USERNAME%` on the CMD command line still returns "juerg" instead of "juergen".

I've gone through the registry twice, but I can't find a clue anymore.

Where has Windows still stored the wrong name?

Comment: The username is only truncated if you are linked to a Microsoft Account.  So, the easy solution to this problem is to unlink the Microsoft Account, when prompted for a username enter the full username you wish to use.  Once you logout of the profile and log back into the profile, the user's profile directory, will reflect the name you entered in the prompt.  At that point you can link the user to a Microsoft Account.

Comment: "Microsoft simply truncates the usernames at directory level to 5 characters." - This is only true with local accounts created during OBE process, which require you to use a Microsoft Account, unless you use the workaround to allow local accounts.  Even if you don't you can simply unlink the MS account, provide the correct profile name, and relink the MS account as I explained in my previous comment. This has been the case since Windows 10. The name of the user directory shouldn't be that important, unless course, it contains a space as most software fails to handle the AppData properly.

Comment: It is Microsoft’s new way of ensuring user profiles are unique. I suggest just adapting to it and ignoring it.  The new way works fine

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1110932/how-do-i-disassociate-microsoft-account-credentials-from-an-account-in-windows-1/1110949#1110949) is some background.

Comment: @Ramhound: You might pack all your comments into an answer.

Comment: @harrymc - I have submitted an answer for Windows 8.1 and one for Windows 10. I linked to my Windows 10 answer. I see no reason to duplicate my answer for Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to reinstall Windows again.
It is important that you first log in locally and then add a Microsoft account later.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.