# Is there a way to change a Windows 11 username?

Tags: windows-11, user-accounts

My name is Fausto and my W11 account got somehow broken when I set it up. For some reason it appears as "faust" in **C:\Users** folder collection and in the **cmd** prompt:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2715]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\faust>
```

I thought I could change this with **netplwiz** Users / Properties but nothing changed even after modifying the Username to "**fausto**" (what I want it to be) and rebooting. The old account name is still there, even though the new Username apparently held. No new account was created.

"faust" is not a heck of a bother nor it harms the system operability in any way. What bothers me is not being able to change that what seems to be a permanent error and I hate when things like these aren't under my control. I'm the Administrator, after all.

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks.

Comment: Windows automatically uses the first 5 letters of your Microsoft account name to name that folder.

Comment: "*I hate when things like these aren't under my control. I'm the Administrator, after all.*" Get used to it with Windows. Microsoft has been moving more and more to "Windows as a Service" model since 2015 where they control more and you control less.

Comment: @BogdanStefanescu Aha, that's how things got screwed; it wasn't I, then. But is there a way to change this? Five letters are not a whole lot of characters.

Comment: @FaustoArinosBarbuto - Disconnect the Microsoft Account, choose a username, then reassociated the profile with the Microsoft Account

Comment: This is nothing to be concerned about.  The 5 character plus Windows ID is unique./

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1814743/windows-11-username-still-truncated Hm, this question has been asked and answered before but I am too lazy to find it. Note that if you do not want a microsoft account they make you jump through hoops in order to create a local account.

Comment: @Gantendo - It's actually the same number steps, it's trivial to create a local account on Windows 11, the answer to that question is even 100% accurate since the answer absolutely is NOT to reinstall Windows.